# Angular 4 application is not instanceable multiple times on the same page

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to create an angular application that can instanceated many times on the same html page, something like this:

```
<app-root name="rebert" age="25"></app-root>
<app-root name="jean" age="25"></app-root>
<app-root name="carry" age="17"></app-root>
```

that was possible in angularjs. why this beatiful fonctionnality has been removed from angular except if there is something i miss;

Thank you

Comment: You dont instanciate the whole app multiple times, you instanciate the components, services, directives...

Comment: I absoulutely know that :). But i need what i said in the question. I need to instanceate the whole app as many as i want on the same page. I need to create a widget app that i can put many times on the same html page.

Comment: Instead of having the root of the app as the parent, just put everything in a component called "sub-parent" or something like that ?

Comment: Not that what i need. I need the app to be instanceated for a specific reason. If it does exists in angular i want to know how ?

Comment: Well I trully dont have an appropriate answer to your question, if however you were to find one in the future we'll be glad to know it, you can answer your own questions !

Comment: I there a way to mount this need to angular team ?

Comment: You can open an issue in [their github](https://github.com/angular)

Comment: OK thanks. This stuff is necessary to make angular run inside Liferay 6.2. I could do that but liferay angular 4 based portlet are not instanceable.